# squareroot of x^2 in limits infinity to -infinity...

Tags: calculus, limits

$\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\bigg|^{\infty}_{-\infty} = ?$

$=\Bigg[\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{(x^2)(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$

$=\Bigg[\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{(x^2)}\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$

$=\Bigg[\frac{x}{a^2x\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$

$=\Bigg[\frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$

$=\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}} - \lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}$

$=\frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{1+0}} - \frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{1+0}}$

$=\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{a^2}$

$=0$

Here's the part i don't get, the above answer is wrong because:

$\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\bigg|^{1}_{-1} = ?$

$ = \frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{1^2+a^2}} - \frac{-1}{a^2\sqrt{(-1)^2+a^2}}$

$ = \frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{1^2+a^2}} + \frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{(1)^2+a^2}}$

$ = \frac{2}{a^2\sqrt{1^2+a^2}}$

which contradicts the first version of this problem above!

I'm curious, how to keep track of the correct sign for $\sqrt{(x^2)}$ in the algebra so that It comes out to the correct answer in the first problem:

$=\frac{2}{a^2}$

Its almost like:

$\sqrt{x^2} = \begin{cases}x &x \ge 0 \\ -x & x \lt 0 \end{cases}$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ i.e $\sqrt{(-4)^2}=\sqrt{16}=4=|-4|$

Comment: its a good point to use absolute value when pulling $x^2$ outside of square root...  i guess you just don't cancel $\frac{x}{|x|}$ in the limits... but know that when you take the limit its like a one....then the sign works out...

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

Set $1/x=h$

$\sqrt{x^2+a^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+a^2h^2}}{|h|}$

Divide the sum into $(-\infty,0];[0,\infty)$

So, for $-\infty<x<0,\sqrt{x^2+a^2}=-\dfrac{\sqrt{1+a^2h^2}}h$

for $x>0,\sqrt{x^2+a^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+a^2h^2}}h$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\bigg|^{\infty}_{-\infty} = ?$

$=\Bigg[\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{(x^2)(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$

$=\Bigg[\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{(x^2)}\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$

$=\Bigg[\frac{x}{a^2|x|\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$

$=\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{a^2|x|\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}} - \lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{a^2|x|\sqrt{(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})}}$

$=\frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{1+0}} - \frac{-1}{a^2\sqrt{1+0}}$

$=\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{a^2}$

$=\frac{2}{a^2}$